# Unable to install package through apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

This kind of an error I'm facing:

```
root@ubuntu-pc:~# reaver
The program 'reaver' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install reaver

root@ubuntu-pc:~# sudo apt-get install reaver

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package reaver

root@ubuntu-pc:~#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `software-properties-gtk` make sure the *universe* repository is checked (alternatively you can check `/etc/apt/sources.list` to verify you have the *universe* repositories enabled). After that run `sudo apt-get update`.

You can verify the package is there with `apt-cache policy reaver`, which should give output like,

```
reaver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4-2
  Version table:
     1.4-2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

showing you that the *universe* repository is now available. Now you should simply be able `sudo apt-get install reaver`.

Otherwise it could be that this time you installed a version older than 12.10 (perhaps 12.04?). Looking at the launchpad page, I only see builds for 12.10 and later: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/reaver